# How to use External Authentication for ASP.NET Boilerplate?

Tags: authentication, aspnetboilerplate

I want to use External Authentication for my project. Can anyone tell me how to use External Authentication for ASP.NET Boilerplate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation on [External Authentication:](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Zero/User-Management#external-authentication)

> UserManager defines an extension point named 'external authentication source'. We can create a class derived from **IExternalAuthenticationSource** and register to the configuration. There is **DefaultExternalAuthenticationSource** class to simplify implementation of IExternalAuthenticationSource. Let's see an example:

```cs
public class MyExternalAuthSource : DefaultExternalAuthenticationSource<Tenant, User>
{
    public override string Name => "MyCustomSource";

    public override Task<bool> TryAuthenticateAsync(string userNameOrEmailAddress, string plainPassword, Tenant tenant)
    {
        // Authenticate user and return true or false
    }
}
```